# Passing a variable through next and previous pages

Tags: php

I start the page with  the:

```
$selectedMenu = $_GET['selectedMenu'];
```

Then I have next and previous functions

```
<?php if ($prev) {  ?>
    <a href='?AID=<?=$prev?>&selectedMenu=$selectedMenu' style='background-image:url(/images/navDivider.png); background-position:right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;'>back&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href='gallery.php?CID=<?=$CID?>&SCID=<?=$SCID?>&selectedMenu=$selectedMenu' style='background-image:url(/images/navDivider.png); background-position:right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;'>back&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
 <?php } ?> 

<?php if ($next){ ?>
    <a href='?AID=<?=$next?>&selectedMenu=$selectedMenu'>&nbsp;next</a>             
<?php } ?>
```

There is a query that pulls the AID, CID, and SCID

But what happens is that the $selectedMenu won't stay after the fist page even though I am passing it in the url. Any clues why it's dropping out?

Comment: Could you use precise technical terminology please. I don't know what "won't stay after the [first] page" or "it's dropping out" mean.

Comment: BTW I think you meant `&selectedMenu=<?=$selectedMenu?>`

Comment: Use the [alternative syntax](http://il.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) it's much more readable for things like that.

Comment: Also, don't use shorthands (`<?= ?>`) it's bad and every time you use it god kills a kitten.

Comment: With a not too precise technical terminology, thanks for helping me get the correct syntax Tomalak. I appreciate it! This works fine.

Comment: What's wrong with (<?= ?>) ? What would you use instead Truth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a query string management class. For example: https://github.com/kenaniah/insight/blob/master/classes/querystring.php

Example usage:

```
<?php
$qs = new QueryString;
$qs->CID = $CID;
print "<a href='blah.php".$qs."'>Link</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($prev) {  ?>
    <a href="?AID=<?php echo $prev; ?>&selectedMenu=<?php echo $selectedMenu; ?>" style="background-image:url(/images/navDivider.png); background-position:right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;">back&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="gallery.php?CID=<?php echo $CID; ?>&SCID=<?php echo $SCID; ?>&selectedMenu=<?php echo $selectedMenu; ?>" style="background-image:url(/images/navDivider.png); background-position:right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;">back&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
 <?php } ?> 

<?php if ($next) { ?>
    <a href="?AID=<?php echo $next; ?>&selectedMenu=<?php echo $selectedMenu; ?>">&nbsp;next</a>             
<?php } ?>
```

It was probably because you had a PHP variable in there without a surrounding PHP start and end tag. Also gave you proper echo statements.

Edit: Damn, realized you already got the answer.